# Как написать итератор в c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть LinkedList :

```
    Node* head
    Node* tail
    size_t size
```

и т.д.

У него есть итератор - `LinkedListIterator`. Он держит внутри себя приватно `Node* ptr` для собственно итерирования.

Нужно реализовать функцию `insert` у `LinkeList`.

```
iterator insert(const_iterator position, const_reference val);
```

Как в 21 веке на C++11/14 написать эту вещь? Не охото писать friend, чтобы LinkedList мог получить доступ к потрохам Iterator'a и взять оттуда ptr.

Comment: Делегируйте работу итератору. Он и без того имеет доступ к потрохам листа.

Comment: Тогда получается что итератор умеет вставлять элементы в коллекцию, это точно не его зона ответственности.

Comment: Разработчики STL с Вами не согласны: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/insert_iterator/

Comment: Хорошо, это аргумент, я соглашусь. Хотя историй и багов где разработчики STL накосячили тоже хватает :)

Comment: Даже для стандартных контейнеров итератор представляет из себя вложенный тип, т.е. имеющий доступ ко всем потрохам самого контейнера.

Comment: @kff, это особый вид, изменяющего итератора, в общем виде итератору не нужно знать контейнера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итераторы так и пишутся — контейнер имеет доступ к потрохам итератора, а обратного доступа нет. В этом плане, ничего не изменилось и не изменится — именно так и задумывалось. Можно, конечно, сделать наоборот — итератор имеет доступ к контейнеру, а обратного доступа нет, но это, на мой взгляд, не правильный подход.

Я бы реализовал так:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    using Iterator = ListIterator<T>;
    ...
};
```

И

```
template<typename T>
class LListIterator
{
    friend LinkedList<T>;
    ...
};
```

---

Посмотрел сейчас реализацию в MSVC, там вообще итераторы полностью публичные. Ну да, а чего себе голову морочить, проще просто `public` написать.

---

Comment: Да, я тоже на MSVC посмотрел. Но вы все равно не ответили на вопрос. Как пишутся-то? Как реализовать в коде, чтобы контейнер имел доступ к итератору? Вообще в комментариях выше написали что итератор это вложенный тип, то есть итератор имеет доступ к потрохам контейнера, а наоборот нет. Вы точно ничего не напутали?

Comment: Да, посмотрел еще здесь - http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs107l/handouts/04-Custom-Iterators.pdf итератор friend контейнера, то есть контейнер имеет доступ к потрохам итератора. Чтобы не писать friend в с++ 11 можно сделать класс итератора и у него вложенный класс контейнера :), тогда все должно работать.

Comment: @Dima00782, мне казалось я ответил — Вы же явно писали, что не хотите писать friend, из Вашего текста, у меня сложилось впечатление, что Вы знаете как его написать. Тем не менее, обновил ответ. Что касается вложенного класса — я бы не стал, зачем? Только засоряет пространство класса.

Comment: Спасибо за пример кода, но я старался без friend написать, но все равно спасибо. Про вложенность похоже недопонимание. В C++11 вложенный класс может по представленному экземпляру обращаться к приватным полям - вот для чего я предложил вложенный класс (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

Comment: @Dima00782, тогда получается, что iterator имеет доступ к контейнеру. Я такой подход не подддерижваю.

Comment: Получается что Iterator имеет доступ только к публичным полям контейнера, все же нормально?

Comment: @Dima00782, если поместите его внутрь List, то Iterator будет иметь доступ и к приватным данным тоже.

Comment: Iterator включает контейнер, я про такое включение.

Comment: @Dima00782, и как Вы себе это представляете. Как Вы такой класс будете использовать? Через `using` делать псевдоним?  Дело Ваше, конечно, но, на мой взгляд, это ужасный подход, который ничем не оправдан.

Comment: Да, я с вами согласен, спасибо прояснение.